# Wordpress Stripping Issue HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using some software for my online store that creates templates for e-commerce products through HTML 5. The problem is that when I put this into WordPress I get plain text and images instead of the template. I was wondering if there is a plugin or some script that can stop woocommerce and word press from stripping the descriptions of my products?

Comment: Please provide more information like what software do you use and screen shot of the issue that you are facing etc so that people here can provide you better guidance.

Comment: Thank you no worries here you go:

Site: http://www.zamiafashion.com

Site is under maintenance so login with username Help and Password helphelp at /wp-admin.

You can see problem at: http://www.zamiafashion.com/shop/ladies-black-lace-above-knee-mini-evening-day-party-formal-work-wedding-dress/

The description is all in one line it should be centered and have header images like it was a professional HTML email.

Comment: Dont worry about username maintenance is now disabled so you can see.